# Enclosing Page Numbers using the `Backref=Pages` Extension of `Hyperref`

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, formatting, back-referencing

I'm using the `backref=pages` extension of the `hyperref` package, as I'd like to have a list of back-reference pages after my bibliographic items. Is there a way to enclose these page numbers in brackets like "[2]" instead of just having the number (without enclosure)?

For example, I'd like for a `bibitem` to appear as

> [1] Witten, E., The Theory of Everything, Any Journal, Volume, Pages
>   (Year) [pg. 1], [pg. 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command responsible for typesetting the back references is `\backrefxxx`, so

```
\renewcommand{\backrefxxx}[3]{%
  [\hyperlink{page.#1}{backref page #1}]}
```

will do. This will make all of "backref page #" a link. If you want only the page number to be a link, do

```
\renewcommand{\backrefxxx}[3]{%
  [backref page \hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}]}
```

Other variations are possible.

Comment: The second variation is perfect for my needs. Thank you!